# Why is Matlab rounding off to 4 places after decimal?

Tags: matlab, truncation, taylor-series

I have the following code that prints/graphs out the result of a Taylor Series Approximation.

```
close all;
clear;
clc;

fprintf('#\tf(pi/3)\t\t\t\tfn(pi/3)\t\t\tEt\n');

% actual function
syms x;
f(x)=exp(-x)*cos(x);
h = ezplot(f);
grid on;
hold on;
set(h,'Color','b', 'LineWidth', 3);

% presets for Taylor.
a=1;
maxorder=10;

% Taylor Series
y(x)=f(a);
for n=1:maxorder
    d(x) = diff(f(x),x,n);
    y(x) = y(x) + d(a)*((x-a)^n)/factorial(n);
    error=double(f(pi/3))-double(y(pi/3));
    fprintf('%.0f\t%.14f\t%.14f\t%.14f\n',n,double(f(pi/3)),double(y(pi/3)),error); 
end
h = ezplot(y);
axis([0, 4.5,-1, 1]);
set(h,'Color','r', 'LineWidth', 3);
set(gca,'FontSize', 15');
title('Taylor Series of e^{-x}cos(x)');
```

However, the table that gets printed out is for some reason getting truncated 4 places after the decimal point. Typing:

```
get(0,'format')
```

into the Matlab terminal tells me the formatting is set to long. I have no clue why this could be happening.

This is what the table looks like:

```
#   f(pi/3)             fn(pi/3)            Et
1   0.17550000000000    0.17480000000000    0.00070000000000
2   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
3   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
4   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
5   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
6   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
7   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
8   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
9   0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
10  0.17550000000000    0.17550000000000    0.00000000000000
```

This rounding seem to happen only with symbolic functions. It does happen when those are not used. Any idea why and how I can fix that?

Comment: I ran your code and the rounding did not happen. For example, the first line was like this: `1 0.17545990358921 0.17477436859764 0.00068553499157`. Did you try restarting Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your output setting `digits(4)`. Set it back to 32 and everything should be okay.

The `digits` functions allows to set the precision of mupad variable precision arithmetic. The precision was reduced to 4 digits for some reason.